# sudo not found in shell of CTRL+ALT+F1

Tags: command-line, bash, login

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Login to shell
3. Type any command: `sudo`, `ls`, `cat`
4. Output:

   ```
    -bash sudo: No such file or directory
   ```

Also when I login, environment variable is printed:

```
-bash: export: '/home/some/path:/home/some/other/path: _not a  valid identifier_
```

It's the`not a valid identifier` part which I believe is causing the problem. I am new to Ubuntu. What I would like to know is

1. How to get sudo working here?
2. Anyway I can edit my `.profile`?

Comment: Your profile shouldn't need `sudo` to edit by you: just edit it using for example `/usr/bin/nano ~/.profile`

Comment: @steeldriver potential answer?? Anyway, you probably still have a issue becuase `sudo` should be available - what is the output of `echo $PATH`, and have you edited any rc files lately (e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`)?

Answer (score 4):

You have trashed the definition of `PATH`, the list of directories the shell searches for commands you type. Thus, when you type `ls` the shell looks at the directories in `$PATH` and doesn't find `/bin/ls`. There is a two-step fix:

```
# First, manually set PATH to something survivable
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

# then edit your `~/.bashrc`, find the line that begins with
# "/home/some/path:/home/some/other/path" and see why Bash wants to
# see an identifier at this point. Bad continuation on the previous line?
nano ~/.bashrc
```

When you've fixed the problem, either log out/in or `source ~/.bashrc` in every shell process you have open.